# SQL View Record Which Is Used More Than Once (Teacher Which Teaches More Than One Module)

Tags: sql, count

I need to get a result from my database where it lists ANY tutors that are teaching in more than ONE module.

Here are the table structures:

```
Student - (studentId,studentName,degree)
Module - (moduleId,moduleName,credit)
Registered - (studentId,moduleId)
Staff - (staffId,staffName,grade)
teaches - (staffId,moduleName)
```

I have made many attempts but I'm doing it wrongly, rather than getting the tutors that teach in more than one module I get a list of all the tutors duplicated as to what they teach.

```
SELECT staff.staffID,staff.staffName
FROM staff
INNER JOIN teaches
ON teaches.staffId = staff.staffId 
INNER JOIN registered
ON registered.moduleId = teaches.moduleId
INNER JOIN student
ON student.studentId = registered.studentId
WHERE staff.staffName < 1;
```

I need to use count in the select some how but I can't figure out how I'd do this.

Comment: I think in order to get staff who teaches more than 2 module you need to maintain moduleId in teaches instead of moluleName than it will easy to get.

Comment: @Shekhar - well `Teaches` _should_ be using `moduleId`, but `moduleName` should be usable (supposing it's unique).

Answer (score 1):

Does it make a difference for selected teacher if it teaches a module that does not have a registered student or maybe the question should be asked is if such a case exists? Cause it occurs to me that there is no need for you to add **student** and **registered** tables to your join. If it does not necessary as I guessed then the correct sql should be like:

```
    SELECT staff.staffID,staff.staffName
    FROM staff
    INNER JOIN teaches
    ON teaches.staffId = staff.staffId 
    GROUP BY staff.staff_id,staff.staffName
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT teaches.moduleId) > 1
```